# Schema image error: "All values provided for url must have the same domain"

Tags: schema.org

[image: structured data tool showing the error]

I'm using a third party image cloud service.  After some days back, I got this error. The Domain and image path are different. How do I fix this?

Comment: Where did you see this error?  Are you using some tool to validate?  If so, what tool?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller tool name google structured data testing tool.
https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/u/0/

Answer (score 4):

That error relates the Googles Carousel Rich Snippet. As you are marking up an ItemList your markup relates to that:

https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/carousel

The way you marked it up comes under the "Summary Page" structure which has the restriction:

> All URLs in the list must be unique, but live on the same domain (the
> same domain or sub/super domain as the current page).

Further reading of the guide and you will find out that the url should refer to another page that contains structured data for a supported type of entity. An image url is not a supported type of url.

If you have no interest in the Google Rich Snippet, you can ignore the error.